# How to update primary key through texbox and datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using windows form with C#, I have a gridview and 4 texboxes and update button, I want to update the selected row through texboxes, I am able to change name, size, date but I can't change Id, I want to be able to change all the columns. How can I do that !!

```
 private void Updatebtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

               SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Ali-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True");
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update stock set Id=@Id, Name= @Name,  Size= @Size, Date=@Date where Id=@Id ", conn);
               conn.Open();
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", textBox1.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox2.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", textBox3.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               MessageBox.Show("Successfully Changed ", "message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
               DataTable ds = new DataTable();
               SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from stock", conn);
               sda.Fill(ds);
               BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
               bs.DataSource = ds;
               dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

           }
```

Comment: While changing the primary key is not a good option, but in your case, it's enough to use 2 different parameters like `@OriginalId` and `@NewId` for changing the value.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Do note the first comment: __Updating a PK is NOT a good idea,.__ In fact it usually exposes a design error. Use meaningful fields as unique fields only and an integer for PK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While updating the primary key is not a good idea, but in your case if you need it, it's enough to:

- Use 2 different parameters like `@OriginalId` for original value and `@NewId` for changed value
- Then assign the original value to `@OriginalId` and the new value to `@NewId`

```
"UPDATE stock SET Id=@NewId, Name= @Name,  Size= @Size, Date=@Date WHERE Id=@OriginalId "
```

Comment: In this case, `OriginalId` will be assigned to texbox10.Text. What about  `NewId` to what will be assigned ?

Comment: In fact `texbox1.Text` should  assign to `@NewId` and for `OriginalId` you can simply store the original value somewhere else, for example in a variable or in your `TextBox.Tag` property

Comment: Let me know if you have got the main point or if you have any question about the answer:)

Answer (score 2):

Look at your command carefully.

```
update ... set Id=@Id ... where Id=@Id
```

You try to set your Id column the value which *already* have. Like;

```
update ... set Id=5 ... where Id=5
```

That's why your column value won't change. Consider to change your `WHERE` part which value you wanna change exactly.

A few things more;

- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and adapter automatically.
- Don't use AddWithValue method. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.
- `DATE` might be [reserved keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in TSQL. You may wanna use it as `[DATE]` instead. Or better, change it to non-future-reserved word.

Comment: That what I were ask about, I want the first ID to be the new value and the ID after `WHERE` to be the new value of the textbox

Comment: @RamaAbdelRahman This is not how `UPDATE` statement works. You put new value on `SET` part and you select conditions which columns will be update on `WHERE` part. For example; `update ... set Id=5 ... where Id=3` updated `Id` columns to `5` _where_ `Id` columns are `3`.